# Fedora update broke my wireless, now constantly creates new wireless interfaces

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

Recently my GNOME software library reported that there were OS updates for my computer (Dell XPS running Fedora 30). Previously everything worked fine, and I believe my kernel version was 5.1.19, the updates included updating to 5.2.7. After updating, I get constant freezes lasting a few seconds, and new wireless interfaces are constantly being created and deleted. Running

```
rfkill list
```

Reports a bluetooth interface, then something like

```
380: phy378: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Where every time I run the command the number identifying the interface is higher. Visually in GNOME, the wifi logo appears and disappears every second or so in the top right corner. Wired ethernet connections work fine.

I thought it could be driver problems with my Killer Ax1650 network card, so I swapped to a Intel AC 9260, with no luck.

Runnign

```
sudo lspci -v
```

gives the following for my network card

```
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0010
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at ed400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

So it shows that iwlwifi is loaded.

I think the freezing occurs with problems with the noveau drivers, because every time I reboot the computer and it freezes a bunch, a bunch of errors appear in the Problem Reporting app, titled 'xorg-x11-drv-noveau' with the subtitle 'System Failure'. Showing more information just says that there is not enough information to report the bug.

I believe there were more updates than just a kernel update, but how likely the 5.2.7 kernel is what is causing my issues? Is there a way to revert back to 5.1.19? That's the only thing I can think of to fix the Wifi, and I don't think there's an easy way to install Nvidia drivers over noveau because my laptop uses Optimus.

I should also include information about my video cards. There is an intel integrated graphics unit, and a discrete Nvidia 1650. Running

```
sudo lshw -class display
```

Gives

```
  *-display                 
   description: 3D controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:135 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
```

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

Comment: Yes, you need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers. Installing those drivers is as easy as if there was only one card/chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation.  <strike>Booting an older kernel fixes it for me.  That's as far as I've been able to get.</strike>

I was able to find this:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/lost-wifi-after-recent-update-intel-9560ngw/2639/5

The long and the short of it is downgrading the firmware appears to fix it:

```
    sudo dnf downgrade -y iwl7260-firmware
    sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi
    sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Probably want to lock the version as well so your next dnf update doesn't bring it back:

```
    sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(versionlock)'
    sudo dnf versionlock add iwl7260-firmware
```

Comment: What ended up fixing it for me was branching off fedora 31's development branch, so my kernel version is now 5.3 (unstable release). Your method would have probably been better and more stable though